# Python struct string to bin

Tags: python, struct, binary

I´m learning Python. 
Seeing the *module struct*, I found a doubt:

Is it possible to convert a "string" to "bin" without giving the length.

For the case (with chars length)

```
F = open("data.bin", "wb")

import struct
data = struct.pack("24s",b"This is an unknown string")
print(data)

F.write(data)

F.close()
```

I´m trying to do the same but with unknown length.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Bytes are already binary so just write them out directly.

Comment: Does it need to be exactly 24 chars in length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the string, use `len` to determine the length of the string.

i.e

```
data = struct.pack("{0}s".format(len(unknown_string)), unknown_string)
```

Comment: Works great! Is it possible to define the "string" part with format...? To use strs = "This is an unkown string" and then struct.pack("{0}s".format(len(strs)),strs) where the second strs should be b"string_content"? Thanks a LOT!

Comment: Yes, you could pass any variable to the `format` function, or the `len` of any string, etc. and then pass a different string as the second parameter to `struct.pack`. I'm not sure if I understand your comment though.

Answer (score 1):

The [Bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray-objects) type is a binary data type, it just stores a bunch of 8bit characters. Note that the code with `struct.pack` ends up creating a bytes object:

```
>>> import struct
>>> data = struct.pack("24s",b"This is an unknown string")
>>> type(data)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> len(data)
24
```

The length of this is 24 as per your format specifier. If you just want to place the bytes-string directly into the file without doing any length checking you don't even need to use the struct module, you can just write it directly to the file:

```
F = open("data.bin", "wb")
F.write(b"This will work")
```

If however you wanted to keep the 24 bytes length you could keep using `struct.pack`:

```
>>> data = struct.pack("24s",b"This is an unknown st")
>>> len(data)
24
>>> print(data)
b'This is an unknown st\x00\x00\x00'
>>> data = struct.pack("24s",b"This is an unknown string abcdef")
>>> print(data)
b'This is an unknown strin'
```

In the case of supplying a bytes that is too short `struct.pack` pads the remainder with 0's and in the case where it's too long it truncates it.

If you don't mind getting the missing space padded out with zeros you can just pass in the bytes object directly to `struct.pack` and it will handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to both...
My new code:

```
F = open("data.bin", "wb")

strs = b"This is an unkown string"

import struct
data = struct.pack("{0}s".format(len(strs)),strs)
print(data)

F.write(data)

F.close()
```